# Creating Qt plugin and using non-virtual functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, qt, plugins, qt4

First of all I use VS 2008 and dynamic build of Qt 4.7.0.

#### interface.h:

```
class PluginInterface
{

public:        
        virtual void foo() = 0;
};

Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(PluginInterface, MY_PLUGIN_VERSION)
```

And I have and class which implements this interface:

#### myplugin.h

```
class MyPlugin: public QObject, public PluginInterface
{
public:
        Q_OBJECT
        Q_INTERFACES(PluginInterface)
        virtual void foo(); // this functions is implemented in cpp file.
        static QString goo(); // this function is also implemented in cpp file.
};
```

So when I use this plugin in other project(MySpecialPlugin) which will be compiled as dynamic-link library(actually also a plugin interface implementation) I can't call
`MyPlugin::goo();`

The header of "MyPlugin.h" is visible for MySpecialPlugin. And Ms VS2008 successfully compile the project. But I have error on link step LNK2001, undefined reference. But when change `static void goo();` to `virtual void goo();` it works.

I'm using Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2 macro for creating plugins.

What I'm doing wrong? Does Qt set additional requirements on implementation of plugin interfaces?

Comment: should your class declaration look like this? http://pastebin.com/dAEM19XU

Comment: You need to link "MySpecialPlugin" with MyPlugin library

Comment: Why haven't you inherited from `PluginInterface` and `QObject` in `MyPlugin`?

Comment: I added MyPlugin as dependency to the MySpecialPlugin project and set project parameter "Link Library Dependencies" to "Yes".

Note: Problem occurs on LINK step on MySpecialPlugin project, not UIC, MOC, Preprocessing, Compiling steps...

Comment: You need to export your class inside library.

Comment: Hm? Can you tell me how can i do this?

Comment: Qt has a whole tutorial on this subject, in case you haven't read it: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/tools-plugandpaint.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all you need to export your class (on windows it's magic like `__declspec(dllexport)` after class keyword when compiling your "myplugin" and `__declspec(dllimport)` when compiling code using it (in this case MySpecialPlugin). You can achieve it with simple define. [read more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

   ```
   #ifdef _WIN32
   #ifdef MYPLUGIN_COMPILE
   #define MYPLUGIN_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
   #else
   #define MYPLUGIN_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
   #endif
   #else
   #define MYPLUGIN_EXPORT
   #endif

   class MYPLUGIN_EXPORT MyPlugin
   {
        // implementation
   };
   ```

   And add MYPLUGIN_COMPILE to preprocessor section of MyPlugin
2. You need to link against exporting library

Calling static and "normal" methods differs from calling virtual methods... static and "normal" methods are always at certain address and your code needs to know where is it... virtual call "checks" class vtable at what address your method has implementation and get that address "dynamicly" from that table. Additionaly win32 VC platform requires to define that something is "exported" (exposed) to access from outside of dll. So basicly if you want to call anything from MyPlugin directly (every member that is not virtual is called directly), you have to export it on win32 VC platform. Note that calling directly virtual method with MyPlugin::foo() will cause same error

Comment: Do I need to do it for Qt plugins? Because most of this routines will be done by Qt to create plugin(for example for function foo())?

Comment: Well it won't be done for your MyPlugin class, so in this special case you have to. Also remember that static method is resolving is different from virutal...

Comment: Ok, but same occurs when i try to access a ordinary function(not virtual, not static).

Comment: I can only speak for the Linux platform, but supplying an entry point for the DLL is handled by the `Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2`, nothing else is required.

Comment: Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2 exports only qt_plugin_query_verification_data qt_plugin_instance functions, so you can only use "interface" methods, not class specific members

Comment: cbamber85 also on linux you don't have to "expose" classes and functions as they're visible for linker by default